# Materialize framework hides <select> html5 elements

Tags: css, html, materialize

I have this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr2uL76L/2/)
which contains a `<select>` element that should display a dropdown list. This works fine if I add `class="browser-default"` to the `<select>` tag, but if I remove it, the dropdown list is hidden, Anyone encounter this problem??Thanks

Need to mention that I need the materialize css added to the dropdown.

Comment: why you can't add this class to your code?

Comment: because it removes the materialize styles...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include this code in your js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

This code help you to override browser defaults and run your JS. This code should be included after Materialize script.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tr2uL76L/4) is JSFiddle. And din't forget to include jQuery to your HTML.